# Button Library Clarification

Tags: html, shared-libraries

I'm using the Button Library by Alex Wolfe - http://alexwolfe.github.io/Buttons/ I download the library and put it in my project then I put the cdn just to make sure I'm using it, when I put the code in my project it doest give me the button and I copied and pasted it but it still doesn't give me the button.

CDN for button library that I put in my code

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/buttons.css">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/buttons.js"></script>
```

Code I put in for the button

```
<a href="to_directions" class="button button-3d-primary button-rounded">press me</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it works.

Are you sure you have a tree like this

- root_folder

  - index.html
  - css

    - buttons.css

If it works with the cdn but not when css file is in your project, it means that the href property is wrong.

If you look at the source code (CTRL + U on Firefox) and click on **css/buttons.css** link, you probably have a 404.

Comment: Im doing this in Rails 4 so, I put the folder in app/assets then created a folder named Library and then put the folders inside that root folder, so how do I make it work?

Comment: I don't know Rails. But your generated code is OK. That probably means that a resource is not found. To verify it, you can launch your browser at __http://localhost:3000/css/buttons.css__ and __http://localhost:3000/js/buttons.js__ and see what happened.